# How to kill jboss on bean initialization failure in the java application

Tags: java, exception, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a java server application running on jboss. I want to kill the jboss process once there is any exception in starting the application (specifically bean initialization). I want to make sure that if there is any exception in connecting to the DB(the bean), both application and jboss process should be killed.  I tried `System.exit(1)`, but it didn't help.

Solved !!

Thanks @daveb. 
I tried your solution. It worked!. But calling an external script looked a little weird to me. I was able to kill JBOSS process using System.exit(1) itself.

The key point is that  System.exit(1) should be called from a new thread. Something like this.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          try {
            System.exit(1);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while calling System.exit(1) {}",e);
          }
        }
      };
      thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put your kill command in a shell script and invoke it from your java bean using ProcessBuilder...here's an example...

```
                    String shutdownScript = "/etc/jboss-as/shutdown.sh";
                    try {

                        log.info("Executing shutdown script: {0}", shutdownScript);

                        String[] command = {"/bin/bash", shutdownScript};
                        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                        Process p2 = p.start();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
                        String line;

                        log.info("Output of running " + command + " is: ");
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            log.info(line);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Unable to execute instance shutdown script: "+ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
                    }
```

A cleaner solution (if you are using JavaEE) would be to create a @Startup bean and run some database checks, if the DB connection is down you can throw a throw a StartException which will automatically undeploy the app for you eg....

```
throw new StartException("Could not initialise DB connection");
```